# Loader against css background image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

Please suggest me how I show the loader in-between button click function to background image fully loading time.

Thanks

```
<html >
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
    //want a loader till the background images loads
        $('#load').show();
        $('#mybody').css('background-image', 'url(http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg)');
        //hide loader after the background images loads
                $('#load').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="mybody" >

<button >Hello</button>
<div style="display:none" id='load'>loading......</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `#load` div until window is fully loaded, then you can use this following code. Also you placed jQuery library file wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{background-image: url(http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg);}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#load').hide();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='load'>loading......</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Abir but I want background image  dynamic so I cant handle it using External or Embedded CSS

Comment: in that case you can make it dynamic by this code `<body style="background-image: url(http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg);">`

Comment: But What about my click function bro? I want that, please have a look in my question.I think you cant get that properly.I have a div and I want to change background image of that div by clicking several li .So $(window).load(function()  is not appropriate here.

Comment: **This should help. Keep your original html** $('button').click(function() {
  var imgLoadStrt = new Date().getTime();
  var img = new Image();
  var imgloadtime;
  img.onload = function() {
   imgloadtime = new Date().getTime() - imgLoadStrt;
   console.log("image took " + imgloadtime + "ms to load");
  };
  img.src = "http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg";
        
        $('#load').show();
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg)');
        
                $('#load').delay(imgloadtime).hide();
    });